# How to split back a char arrayList into two different char array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I've have this code here:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] randChar1 = new char[3];
        char[] randChar2 = new char[3];
        char sym = '<';
        char[] charCombine = new char[6];

        System.out.print("The string generated is: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            Random r = new Random();
            randChar1[i] = (char) (65 + r.nextInt(26));
            System.out.print(randChar1[i]);
            randChar2[i] = (char) (97 + r.nextInt(26));
            System.out.print(randChar2[i]);

        }
        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<char[]> al = new ArrayList<>();

        al.add(randChar1);
        al.add(randChar2);

        Sort(al, sym);
    }

    static void Sort(ArrayList<char[]> al3, char symA) {

    }
}
```

I've added two different char array which is **randChar1** and **randChar2** to the arrayList **al** in the main method.Now, I need to pass the ArrayList from the main method to the **Sort** method. I've pass the ArrayList to the **Sort** method. How to I split back the two char array in the Sort method? And after that how do I sort those char array by ascending and descending order, depends on the ASCII table?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: what is your question, could you be specific ?

Comment: Try first for yourself. Then if you get an error, come back and ask (remember to post here the error)

Comment: so you want us to code for you? if not show us what you've done

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to ask for a solution to a homework problem and no solution by the author is presented.